# Html escaping in java?

Tags: java

Is there a standard class in Java that has a method to HTML-escape a string?

```
< ... &lt;
> ... &gt;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there isn't. You can use [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang) [`StringEscapeUtils#escapeHtml4`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeHtml4%28java.lang.String%29) for this.

---

**Update**: if you have an aversion against 3rd party libraries and/or prefer homegrowing, then loop over the String's characters and determine the character in a `switch` and replace it by the escaped character. You can find [here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0306.html) and [here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=96) an example. But still, using `StringEscapeUtils` is easier on long term.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String encodeHTML(String s)
{
StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();
for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++)
{
     char c = s.charAt(i);
            if( c=='<' )
            {
               out.append("&lt;"+(int)c+";");
            }
            else if(c=='>'){
                 out.append("&gt;"+(int)c+";");
            }
            else
            {
                out.append(c);
            }
}
return out.toString();
```

}

Comment: ...and that is why you should never use a "home made" escaping function. (it misses several items)

Answer (score 0):

No but you could write one:

Iterate over string:

- When char is > output `&gt;`
- When char is < output `&lt;`
- When char is & output `&amp;`
- When char unicode value is outside 32..126 output `&#...;` where ... is the char unicode value.
- else output char